# How to display the position within an array with Cosmos DB SQL

Tags: json, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a problem attempting to select from a document array in Cosmos-db. (SQL-api)

I am able to select the values from the array however I would like to be able to display each of the values position within the array also.

Sample JSON document:

```
{
    "Type": "SampleJSONMessage",
"Version": "1",
"Reference": "Test",
"DateTime": "2019-03-29T15:16:11.503Z",
"Configuration": {
    "MessageType": "1",
    "MessageConfig": "100",
    "Source": [
        {
            "Source": "Stream1"
        },
        {
            "Source": "Stream2"
        },
        {
            "Source": "Stream3"
        },
        {
            "Source": "Stream4"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

I execute this:

select c.Configuration.Source from c

which returns this:

```
[
{
    "Source": "Stream1" 
},
{
    "Source": "Stream2"
},
{
    "Source": "Stream3"
},
{
    "Source": "Stream4"
}
]
```

This is what I would like to display:

```
[
{
    "Source": "Stream1" ,
    "Position": "1"
},
{
    "Source": "Stream2",
    "Position": "2"
},
{
    "Source": "Stream3",
    "Position": "3"
},
{
    "Source": "Stream4",
    "Position": "4"
}
]
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While a [specific index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-overview) is stored inside CosmosDB for each array element, the SQL API doesn't currently have a method for accessing it directly. A user defined function will work though.

Here is the UDF I added to my collection:

```
function ADD_INDEX(array){
    array.forEach(function(item, index){item.Position = index.toString()});
    return array;
}
```

And the modified query to use this to get the output you want:

```
select udf.ADD_INDEX(c.Configuration.Source) AS Source from c
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks SamaraSoucy.